# get the apple id that the user used in his/her iphone in my ios app

Tags: ios

I want to know if there's a way for me to get the current apple id that the user used in his/her iphone for my app. I just need the username because i need to get the email of the user. Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you just ask the user to enter their email address and not try taking it from them unknowingly...?

Comment: @nhgrif Probably because they can say no (which they should... I'm just being cynical here)

Comment: No, you can't get the id or the username. And that's a good thing for users.

Comment: Well I am developing an app that's just an ios version of an existing andriod app. In andriod apps i think they allow that to get the email of the user used in google, but in ios I saw a post that says Apple doesn't allow that because of privacy issues, Well that's a good thing. So I thought I'll just let the user enter their email. Thanks for replies. :) Good Luck to All

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. If it were, unscrupulous app developers might silently harvest personally identifying information from users, like their e-mail address, and then send them spam.

Comment: Yes I have already thought of that, I decided to just let the user enter an email address. Thanks by the way for the answer.